# jQuery hover to replace the HTM hover property with fade-in effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am in search of a jQuery technique or plugin, using which our default hover property should become the fade-in jQuery hover property. Suppose if we place the mouse cursor on any `div`, its background should be fade-in hovered. 
Please see this image.

> [image]

Comment: There are two possibilities: either you want to replace the color of the background, or you want to "fade" the color (by reducing it's opacity). By inducing "opacity" you make the div less or more transparent. Opacity takes values from 0.0 to 1. Below, I have posted an answer covering both cases. Hope it helps you. Theo

Comment: [Most browsers now support CSS3 transitions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), so unless you are using jQuery for something else on your site, don't bother with the unnecessary JS

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CSS3 transitions. Even though CSS3 transitions aren't supported in IE you would still get the hover effect in IE just without the fade.

The basic idea is that you use JavaScript to add and remove a class on hover. You then use CSS3 transitions to animate the background colour transition.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="entry">
     Lorem Ipsum
</div> 
<div class="entry">
     Dolor Etam
</div> 
<div class="entry">
     Lorem Elar
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.entry').mouseenter(function (event) {
    $(this).addClass('active');                
});
$('.entry').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.entry {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;    
    -webkit-transition:background-color 2s,-webkit-transform 2s;
    transition:background-color 2s, transform 2s;    
}

.entry.active {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d57BW/

Reference for CSS3 transitions usage: http://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: Also a very good solution. Except from the pure js way which I described below, css transitions and also be very handy in many cases. Nice thinking!

Comment: Good point for a pure CSS approach just using :hover pseudo class is of course the easiest. I should really have started with that. The main downside would be that IE8 and below would ignore hover states on non-anchors unless you use a strict doctype and if you use a strict doctype it can cause some performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery does not animate colors.
If you want to **replace** background color, use the [jquery-color plugin](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-color/2.1.2/jquery.color.js)

*(The code for changing just the opacity without plugins is at the bottom)*

Now the code for replacing color:

HTML:

```
<div id ="myDiv">TEST</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv{background-color:red; width:300px; height:200px; text-align:center;}
```

JS:

```
$("#myDiv")
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "yellow"}, 'slow');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"red"},'slow');
  });
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2khZe/

If you want just to **chance the opacity** of the already set background color, you dont need the plugin, and just replace the above js code to this:

```
$("#myDiv")
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 'slow');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1},'slow');
  });
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/w2Z7x/

Hope it helps you.

Theo.

Answer (score 0):

```
without javascript
//this code your test 
.entry{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    height:120px;
    line-height:120px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:0.5px;
    transition:background-color 0.7s linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition:background-color 0.7s linear 0.1s;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.entry:hover{
    background-color:#eee;
    transition:background-color 0.7s linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition:background-color 1s linear 0.1s;
}
```